# Parsing json data to a table but some rows are not fetched

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, html-table

I am using google maps api to get an address based on a given longitude and latitude. There can be several calls to the api, the longitudes and latitudes are loaded from a database.

I want to go through all the api calls and get the formatted address and display it in a table.

The table layout is as follows: count / ref / longitude / latitude / address

My script is as follows:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "...";
$databasetable = "import1";
$databasetable2 = "data1";
$databaseusername ="...";
$databasepassword = "...";


$con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from $databasetable;");

$data = array();

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $data[$index] = $row;
     $index++;
}
$count = 1;
?>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$key['latitude'].','.$key['longitude'].'&sensor=true';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $dataReceived = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    if(!empty($dataReceived['results'][0]['formatted_address']))
    {
        $formattedAddress = $dataReceived['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
    }else{
        $formattedAddress = '';
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$count?></td>
        <td><?=$key['id']?></td>
        <td><?=$key['latitude']?></td>
        <td><?=$key['longitude']?></td>
        <td><?=$formattedAddress?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $count++;
}
?>
</table>
<?php
@mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now, if you go to this link: http://www.ryansmurphy.com/crawler/get-data.php the problem becomes clear. Some rows, dont have an address. IF you keep refreshing youll notice that it seems to be different rows each time that dont have an address. Its extremely odd.

If you take one of the rows that doesnt have an address and put the longitude and latitude into the api call, (see the link to the api call in the script above) youll notice there is data for the formatted address.

What am I doing wrong?

All of the rows should returning the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for errors.  The geocoder is subject to a quota and a rate limit.  Geocoding a large number of addresses every time your page loads is not a good idea (where a large number is a number greater than ~10).

Comment: So your suggesting, put a limit of ten on the database call of long and lats?

Comment: If you have a database which contains the addresses, cache the geocoded coordinates in there (to comply with the terms of use, and re-geocode them periodically).  Use the coordinates from the database, not by geocoding the addresses on load.  Or if you are doing this to populate the database, then yes do 10 at a time with a delay between groups of 10.  Although actually what I suggested was "Check for errors".  If you get an error (that implies you are over quota), delay for a period of time and re-try.

Comment: this could be a solution but it says nothing one the usage policy about how many calls at a time you can make, it only says there is a limit of 2500 a day

Comment: That is true.  The actual rate limit is not specified and can vary with server load.  The number ~10 comes from experience with the javascript geocoding service in the v3 Google Maps Javascript API, the web service might be different.

Comment: you inspired, on every 5 count, i implemented a 5 second sleep timer. thank you i will accept your answer as your thoughts inspired mine.